# How can I make a python app to a exe file?

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyinstaller, auto-py-to-exe

I have a python app that downloads video's from youtube. In the IDE (Pycharm), the program works. But when I use auto-py-to-exe then the files are good but then it doesn't work.

I add the files that are neccensery for the program to work but It gives error.

Here is the error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "Main.py", line 1, in 
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyQt5'

When I add the folder PyQt5 from my IDE then it goes to another error and so forth. I was doing this for 2 hours straight and eventually nothing happens and crashes when it launches so adding folders from IDE is not working.

Can someone help me to convert it to a working app with a exe?

I already did auto-py-to-exe and thought it would work but it doesn't. It crashes when started.
I hope that someone can help me to make it working so I can distrubute it to friends and family who wants the tool. Now I can't.

Comment: Sorry but StackOverflow is not a tutorial website. If you did try to use auto-py-to-exe, then tell us what you did and, possibly, the output of running it from a shell or command prompt.